# How to remove any commands that begins with "echo" from history

Tags: bash

I have tried the below

```
history -d $(history | grep "echo.*" |awk '{print $1}')
```

But it is not deleting all the commands from the history with echo

I want to delete any commands start with echo

like

```
echo "mamam"
echoaaa
echo "hello"
echooooo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to remove `echo` entries :

```
for d in $(history | grep -Po '^\s*\K(\d+)(?= +echo)' | sort -nr); do history -d $d; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a

```
 history -d $(history | grep -E "^ *[0-9]+ *echo" | awk '{print $1})
```

The history command produces one column of event number, followed by the command. We need to match an *echo*, which is following such a event number. The *awk* then prints just the event number.

An alternative without reverting to awk would be:

```
history -d $(history | grep -E "^ *[0-9]+ *echo" | grep -Eow '[0-9]+)
```

Comment: not working   .....history -d $(history | grep "^echo")
-bash: history: -d: option requires an argument
history: usage: history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filename] or history -ps arg [arg...]

Comment: @RajarshiDas : Fixed - please try it.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
history -w
sed -i '/^echo.*/d' ~/.bash_history
history -c
history -r
```